# Какие функции swap нужны для класса

Tags: c++, классы, swap, дружественная-функция

В данный момент имеется функция-член класса `swap`:

```
void Implementation::swap(Implementation& other) noexcept
{
    using std::swap;

    swap(this->m_number, other.m_number);
    swap(this->m_string, other.m_string);
    swap(this->m_vector, other.m_vector);
}
```

а также свободная функция `swap`, вызывающая `Implementation::swap`:

```
inline void swap(Implementation& lhs, Implementation& rhs) noexcept
{
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}
```

Такая техника описана у *Скотта Мейерса*, а также используется в бусте.

Далее я натолкнулся на мнение, что функция-член *засоряет* класс, соответсвенно, убрать ее, а лучше сделать функцию `swap` другом класса и написать нечто такое:

```
class Implementation
{
public:
    inline friend void swap(Implementation& lhs, Implementation& rhs) noexcept;
};

inline void swap(Implementation& lhs, Implementation& rhs) noexcept
{
    using std::swap;

    swap(lhs.m_number, rhs.m_number);
    swap(lhs.m_string, rhs.m_string);
    swap(lhs.m_vector, rhs.m_vector);
}
```

В объяснении приводились доводы в пользу ADL, но довольно туманно и до конца их я не понял. Объясните, пожалуйста, какая техника написания `swap` является сейчас наилучшей?

P.S. Еще вопрос относительно стиля: должна ли функция `swap` возвращать что-то, например, `Implementation&` или же стоит обойтись `void`?

Comment: А для чего может быть удобно не-void?

Comment: учитывая, что swap имеет noexcept, то можно возвратить bool/int с кодом возврата:) :) А то вдруг swap не отработал.

Comment: @VladD я полагаю, не-void в случае вызова через . еще каких-то функций-членов в той же инструкции. Не знаю, буду ли я так писать в своем коде, но в бусте встречал.

Comment: @KoVadim, `swap` c `noexcept`, означает, что он __никогда__ не завершается с ошибкой, возвращаемое значение у `swap` это неканонично.

Comment: @ixSci а почему не нужна? Можете пояснить? Оставлять только ф-ю-член?

Comment: @ixSci м, то ест, я не могу определить функцию вида `bool make_good() noexcept {}` ? А то, что swap не должен возвращать значения, это я знаю (там смайлы стоят).

Comment: @Jenssen, неправильно я написал. Нужна эта функция для ADL как раз. Стал с C# языки путать :(

Comment: @KoVadim, можно конечно. Я конкретно про `swap`. Это как раз нормально для `noexcept` функции иметь возвращаемое значение.

Comment: noexcept говорит только то, что исключение с этой функции не вылетит. А то, может ли он завершиться с ошибкой - он не говорит. swap может отработать неверно и noexcept только исключение не выпустит (а сразу std::terminate дернет).

Comment: @KoVadim, ещё раз перечитайте мой комментарий по `swap`, пожалуйста. `noexcept` у `swap` это гарантия что ничего не может пойти не так, ни при каких обстоятельствах. Там не может быть исключений.

Comment: @ixSci Так если у функции указан noexcept, это разве гарантирует, что внутри не может возникнуть ошибка (например, неправильный ввод данных пользователем), которая не вовлекает в действие механизм генерации исключений либо вовлекает его, но проглатывает исключение?

Comment: @ixSci и основной мой вопрос - надо ли заниматься friend функцией или оставить все как есть с двумя? Если знаете, где такая проблема (про friend) рассмотрена, можете скинуть ссылку?

Comment: @ixSci я внимательно читал. А Вы - нет. функция с noexcept может бросить исключение. Ей никто не запрещает. Да, умный компилятор чуть поругает, но не более. Другое дело, что такое приложение упадет и try-catch не поможет.

Comment: @Jenssen У `noexcept` вышел fail с названием. Oно должно называться наподобие `terminate_on_throw`. В языке сейчас по факту вообще нет никаких механизмов для провери исключений во время компиляции. Все попытки их добавить были завернуты рабочей группой по стандартизации  С++. Зато теперь в C++ есть стандартная реализация дзета-функции Римана...

Comment: @KoVadim, да причём тут может или не может? Вы понимаете, что `noexcept` это контракт? Ставя `noexcept` у `swap` программист __гарантирует__, что никаких исключений или ошибок эта функция сгенерировать не может. CC Jenssen

Comment: исключения != ошибка.

Comment: @VTT, в C++ `throw()` существовал незнамо сколько лет, помогло? Если не ошибаюсь, то в лагере Java очень много людей против checked exceptions, т.е. функционал этот как минимум неоднозначен.

Comment: @Jenssen, Вам решать. Я бы оставил две, т.к. не люблю `friend`, но это дело вкуса.

Comment: @ixSci да, так и сделаю. Не вижу смысла изменять привычке :)